# what should be web2print application architecture?

Tags: php, jquery, html, web

i am developing a web2print application in PHP
which will let the people create custom greetings and business cards etc...can anyone suggest the suitable architecture for these kind of apps..?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general and I don't think you'll get any usable answer here. Perhaps it would be better if you could revise it. Yet what I think you need is of two sections. First you need a composition system (editor, store and restore). Second an engine to print your documents into your output type (jpeg/pdf).